# Iteratively split output of a stream in stdin

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq, xargs

I have a large JSON file that I am streaming with `jq`.

This can be used as a test file:

```
{
    "a": "some",
    "b": [
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        },
        {
            "d": "some"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to save separate files once a defined number of lines has been provided in STDIN. Multiple answers (

[How can I split one text file into multiple *.txt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031144/how-can-i-split-one-text-file-into-multiple-txt-files),

[How can I split a large text file into smaller files with an equal number of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-can-i-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-an-equal-number-of-lin),

[Using jq how can I split a very large JSON file into multiple files, each a specific quantity of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808581/using-jq-how-can-i-split-a-very-large-json-file-into-multiple-files-each-a-spec),

[Split a JSON array into multiple files using command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385830/split-a-json-array-into-multiple-files-using-command-line-tools))

suggest the use of `split` piped to the initial command.

```
jq -c --stream 'fromstream(0|truncate_stream(inputs|select(.[0][0]=="b")| del(.[0][0:2])))' ex.json | split -l 4 --numeric-suffixes=1 - part_ --additional-suffix=.json
```

This works, however, based on my knowledge of the `|` in unix, it takes the output of the first command and sends it to the second so STDIN will contain all of the lines (making the stream useless, although STDIN will likely not go out of memory as it can be saved on disk).

I have read that `xargs` can send a predefined number of lines to a command, so I tried this:

```
jq -c --stream 'fromstream(0|truncate_stream(inputs|select(.[0][0]=="b")| del(.[0][0:2])))' ex.json | xargs -I -l5 split -l 4 --numeric-suffixes=1 - part_ --additional-suffix=.json
```

However, no output is generate, plus the `|` is still there so I am assuming I would get the same behavior. In addition, I believe split will overwrite the previously created files as it would be a new invocation.

Does anyone have any advice? Am I missing something in my `unix` terminal knowledge?

(This question [How to 'grep' a continuous stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream) lists how to grep a continuous stream using the `--line-buffered` approach, is there an equivalent for split?)

Comment: _"the | in unix, it takes the output of the first command and sends it to the second so STDIN will contain all of the lines"_ No, the commands in a pipe run in parallel; each command might do a little buffering internally for optimizing IO though.

Comment: `fromstream(2 | truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "b")))` is how it's done idiomatically, by the way

Comment: @Fravadona so the command I have will actually be doing what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Guido Muscioni, if you found a satisfactory answer. Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Fravadona:

> > "the | in unix, it takes the output of the first command and sends it to the second so STDIN will contain all of the lines"

> No, the commands in a pipe run in parallel; each command might do a little buffering internally for optimizing IO though.

So the indicated command has the expected behavior.